# how to connect to a database (postgresql) from frontend and backend without using any library

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, go, backend

Please explain how to access a databases from a web app without using any library. I want make query and other database operation without using any library.

Comment: In a phrase: You can't.  Strictly speaking, you'll at minimum need a network library, then write your own database access layer. But why would you want to avoid using a proper database library?

Comment: @Flimzy  I want to learn how this things work.  Can you give me some resources.

Comment: The proper way to learn how things work is by using the proper library. But resource requests are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Flimzy i want to learn how to implement them

Comment: Start by reading the standard one.

Comment: You are to be commended that you want to understand how things work on the "inside". However, expect to walk a rather long and unsatisfying way of reading technical descriptions on [wire protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_protocol), implementing them and do the whole  "implement=>test=>debutg=>implement" cycle, only to reinvent the wheel, with the slight chance of improving on **one** database driver. If that still sounds interesting to you, I suggest to start reading the drivers for the database you are most familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the standard sql library and see how they did that. Next look at some library that uses that standard sql library.

But ehm, by the time you have something working, you'll probably put it inside a... library so if you'll ever succeed to have it without a library, I have my doubts on that.